# SQLite transactionscope performance issue

Tags: c#, performance, sqlite, transactions

I'm using ANTS performance profiler to search for performance issues within my application.

I'm getting a high CPU percentage at using a transaction scope like the following:
[image]

This method is only called once(When application starts)
Why does it give me a high percentage? Is the Transaction scope a bad way for a select statement that gets called only once?

**edit:**

There are more methods using another method with the same transactionscope with a select statement, however these methods gets called every 1000ms(1 second).

When I delete the transactionscope, the output window in vs will tell me that the database locks sometimes. So it is recommended for me to use the transactionscope, but it will give me lower performance, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only issuing a select statement there is no need for transaction so you can safely remove that statement.

Also, if the statement is executed only once at an application startup I wouldn't worry about it.